# Does the way CALayer generate its contents Affect its scale animation?

Tags: ios, animation

```
@interface CircleRevealLayer : CALayer

@end

@implementation CircleRevealLayer

- (instancetype)init
{
    if (self = [super init]) {
        [self setNeedsDisplay];
        [self displayIfNeeded];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)display
{

    self.contents = (__bridge id)([self maskImage].CGImage);

    self.contentsGravity = kCAGravityCenter;
}

- (UIImage *)maskImage
{
    static UIImage *mask = nil;

    if (!mask) {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT));

        UIBezierPath* bezierPath = UIBezierPath.bezierPath;
        [bezierPath moveToPoint: CGPointMake(209.5, 368)];
        [bezierPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(207, 370.5) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(208.12, 368) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(207, 369.12)];
        [bezierPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(209.5, 373) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(207, 371.88) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(208.12, 373)];
        [bezierPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(212, 370.5) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(210.88, 373) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(212, 371.88)];
        [bezierPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(210.98, 368.49) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(212, 369.67) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(211.6, 368.94)];
        [bezierPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(209.5, 368) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(210.57, 368.18) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(210.05, 368)];
        [bezierPath closePath];
        [bezierPath moveToPoint: CGPointMake(411, 0)];
        [bezierPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(411, 736) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(411, 0) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(411, 736)];
        [bezierPath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(-3, 736)];
        [bezierPath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(-3, 0)];
        [bezierPath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(411, 0)];
        [bezierPath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(411, 0)];
        [bezierPath closePath];
        [UIColor.grayColor setFill];
        [bezierPath fill];

        mask = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();


        //mask = [UIImage imageNamed:@"mask.PNG"];
    }

    return mask;
}

@end






@interface CircleRevealView : UIView

@end

@implementation CircleRevealView

+ (Class)layerClass{
    return [CircleRevealLayer class];
}

@end
```

then, I create it like this:

```
_maskView = [[CircleRevealView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];

_maskView.frame = self.view.bounds;
```

and add a scale animation:

```
POPSpringAnimation *springAnimation = [POPSpringAnimation animation];
springAnimation.property = [POPAnimatableProperty propertyWithName:kPOPViewScaleXY];
springAnimation.toValue=[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(80, 80)];
springAnimation.velocity=[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(1, 1)];       // change of value units per second
springAnimation.springBounciness=20;    // value between 0-20 default at 4
springAnimation.springSpeed=3;
springAnimation.name=@"scaleXY1";
springAnimation.delegate=self;
[_maskView pop_addAnimation:springAnimation forKey:@"scaleXY1"];
```

the mask.PNG is just a white image with a hole in the center.

when I use UIBezierPath to draw the contents and assign it to the layer, the scale animation seems to happen from the top-left corner of the layer;
but if I instead use a image , the scale animation seems to happen from the center of it.

what I want is to generate dynamic contents with Core Graphics and scale the layer like when I use mask.PNG

update:
UIBezierPath
[image]

mask.PNG[image]

the mask.PNG is generated from the UIBezierPath code, with the PaintCode.

Comment: "when I use UIBezierPath to draw the contents and assign it to the layer, the scale animation seems to happen from the top-left corner of the layer; but if I instead use a image , the scale animation seems to happen from the center of it." I don't see you doing this choice in the code, and I don't understand what distinction you are making, since the contents is _always_ an image. Can you clarify?

Comment: like the effect in the gif

Comment: I'm not asking about the effect. I'm asking what your code looks like in the two cases "when I use UIBezierPath to draw the contents and assign it to the layer... but if I instead use a image" Please show both for purposes of comparison.

Comment: in the maskImage method,I comment out the image way

Comment: check the layer's anchorPoint, ensure it's set to (0.5,0.5)

Comment: done that, the anchorPoint is (0.5, 0.5)